# How do I configure unprivileged Linux containers?

Tags: arch-linux, lxc

I'm trying to set up [unprivileged LXC containers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_Containers#Enable_support_to_run_unprivileged_containers_(optional)) and failing at every turn. I think I've followed every relevant step of the guide:

- Normal users are allowed to create unprivileged containers:

  ```
  $ sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone
  kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone = 1
  ```
- The control groups PAM module is enabled:

  ```
  $ grep -F pam_cgfs.so /etc/pam.d/system-login
  session optional pam_cgfs.so -c freezer,memory,name=systemd,unified
  ```
- The UID and GID mappings are set up:

  ```
  $ cat /etc/lxc/default.conf
  lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 65536
  lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 65536
  lxc.net.0.type = veth
  lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
  lxc.net.0.flags = up
  lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx
  $ cat /etc/subuid
  root:100000:65536
  $ cat /etc/subgid
  root:100000:65536
  ```
- The network is set up:

  ```
  $ grep --invert-match --regexp='^#' --regexp='^$' /etc/default/lxc-net
  USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
  LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr0"
  LXC_ADDR="10.0.3.1"
  LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
  LXC_NETWORK="10.0.3.0/24"
  LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.0.3.2,10.0.3.254"
  LXC_DHCP_MAX="253"
  ```
- The services look fine:

  ```
  $ systemctl status --lines=0 --no-pager lxc.service lxc-net.service 
  ● lxc.service - LXC Container Initialization and Autoboot Code
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lxc.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-03-08 15:31:47 NZDT; 40min ago
       Docs: man:lxc-autostart
             man:lxc
   Main PID: 4147 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/lxc.service

  ● lxc-net.service - LXC network bridge setup
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lxc-net.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2019-03-08 15:31:45 NZDT; 40min ago
   Main PID: 4099 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
     Memory: 8.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/lxc-net.service
             └─4121 dnsmasq -u dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/lxc/dnsm…
  ```
- The packages are up to date and I've just rebooted.

Even so, I can't create containers:

```
$ lxc-create -n test -t download
lxc-create: test: parse.c: lxc_file_for_each_line_mmap: 100 No such file or directory - Failed to open file "/home/user/.config/lxc/default.conf"
lxc-create: test: conf.c: chown_mapped_root: 3179 No uid mapping for container root
lxc-create: test: lxccontainer.c: do_storage_create: 1310 Error chowning "/home/user/.local/share/lxc/test/rootfs" to container root
lxc-create: test: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4801 You do not have subuids or subgids allocated
lxc-create: test: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4802 Unprivileged containers require subuids and subgids
lxc-create: test: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_create: 1891 Failed to create (none) storage for test
lxc-create: test: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 327 Failed to create container test
```

**Is there anything obviously wrong with this setup?** There's no mention anywhere in the linked article about ~/.config/lxc/default.conf, and I don't understand why it says I haven't allocated subuids and subgids.

Additional info:

- Running `lxc-create` as root works, but this is explicitly about creating containers as a normal user.
- `cp /etc/lxc/default.conf ~/.config/lxc/default.conf` gets rid of the complaint about the configuration file, but results in this message instead:

  > lxc-create: playtime: conf.c: chown_mapped_root: 3279 lxc-usernsexec failed: No such file or directory - Failed to open ttyNo such file or directory - Failed to open tt

Comment: "Unprivileged containers require subuids and subgids". [`man subuid`](https://manpages.debian.org/subuid.5); `man subgid`. Normally this should be created when the user is created, but if your user was created a long time ago, this might not have been.  Put compatible values in lxc.idmap (or lxc2's equivalent). Now check the next batch of errors heh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a new project, or do you have a choice?  Why not use LXD instead of LXC - much easier to use and you get to the same place.  I started out with lxc and quickly made the switch because I was interested in running unprivileged containers which is not easy in LXC, but is the default in LXD.

Take a look here to start:
https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/comparing-lxd-vs-lxc/24

It's been a few months since I last installed/used it, but here are my notes on installation:

As LXD evolves quite rapidly, we recommend Ubuntu users use our PPA:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/lxd-stable
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# apt-get install lxd
```

The package creates a new “lxd” group which contains all users  allowed to
talk to lxd over the local unix socket. All members of the  “admin” and
“sudoers” groups are automatically added. If your user isn’t  a member of
one of these groups, you’ll need to manually add your user  to the `lxd`
group.

Because group membership is only applied at login, you then either  need to
close and re-open your user session or use the `newgrp lxd`  command in the
shell you’re going to interact with lxd from.

```
newgrp lxd
```

https://blog.ubuntu.com/2015/03/20/installing-lxd-and-the-command-line-tool
2018/10/22

---

To the best of my knowledge you can even run LXD in a virtual machine so you can give it a quick try without messing up whatever system you are working on.

Not exactly the answer to the question you asked, but I hope you find it a helpful alternative.

Comment: I specified Arch Linux and LXC, but I might give LXD a try sometime.

Comment: I don't use Arch Linux, but from the wiki, it appears that LXD works on Arch - maybe this is helpful: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXD)  - Once you get LXD set up it's very easy to work with.

Comment: I got as far as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/505227/3645) - it's enormously difficult to set up and debug this, especially given the minimal documentation.

Comment: -1 because the user is explicitly asking about use of LXC. IMO suggesting an alternate tool in a comment is reasonable, but not as an answer...

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason as given by @JeremyDavis

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I've had the same issue recently which was fixed by following quite a specific error I was given:

```
lxc-create: my-container: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4738 You must either run as root, or define uid mappings
lxc-create: my-container: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4739 To pass uid mappings to lxc-create, you could create
lxc-create: my-container: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4740 ~/.config/lxc/default.conf:
lxc-create: my-container: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4741 lxc.include = /etc/lxc/default.conf
lxc-create: my-container: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4742 lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 65536
lxc-create: my-container: conf.c: suggest_default_idmap: 4743 lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 65536
lxc-create: my-container: lxccontainer.c: do_lxcapi_create: 1869 Failed to create (none) storage for my-container
lxc-create: my-container: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 327 Failed to create container my-container
```

This was quite an easy fix:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/lxc
touch ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
echo "lxc.include = /etc/lxc/default.conf" >> ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
echo "lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 65536" >> ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
echo "lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 65536" >> ~/.config/lxc/default.conf
```

Remember to up date the user and group IDs

Also, on a side note if you recieve the error:

```
Setting up the GPG keyring
ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver
```

It's because of this: https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/3068

To fix it just add `-- --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80` to the end of your create command e.g.

```
lxc-create -t download -n my-container -- --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
```

Hope this helps others if it didn't at least help you

Comment: `p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80` doesn't work. Use `keyserver.ubuntu.com:80` instead. Also, make *sure* you use `lxc.idmap = xxxx` NOT lxc-idmap =. Made that typo mistake and it took me hours to figure out because LXC's error messages are not helpful!

Answer (score 0):

i've wrote a simple script to convert a classic LXC container privileged to unprivileged:

Set second UID - GID (subuid guid) for root user:

```
usermod --add-subuids 1258512-1324047 root
usermod --add-subgids 1258512-1324047 root
```

Alternative Manual for set of sub(UID-GID):

```
echo "root:1258512:65536" >> /etc/subuid
echo "root:1258512:65536" >> /etc/subgid
```

Set permission for unprivileged container dir
note: all UID and GID are added with the offset of root sub(uid-gid)

```
subUid=$(grep root /etc/subuid | cut -d: -f2 | head -1) for i in $(find /var/lib/lxc/nameofcontainer/ -print) do
        ## Get numeric owner of current file/dir
        actProp=$(stat -c '%u:%g' "$i")
        actPropUid=$(echo ${actProp} | cut -d: -f1)
        actPropGid=$(echo ${actProp} | cut -d: -f2)
        ## Calculed shifted owner
        newUid=$(( $actPropUid + $subUid ))
        newGid=$(( $actPropGid + $subUid ))
        ## set new owner
        if [ $actPropUid -lt 65536 ] ; then
                chown ${newUid}:${newGid} "$i"
        fi done 
chown ${subUid}:${subUid} /var/lib/lxc/nameofcontainer/
```

Set in /var/lib/lxc/nameofcontainer/config the options for launch unprivileged:

```
echo "lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/debian.userns.conf" >> /var/lib/lxc/${CT}/config
echo "lxc.idmap = u 0 $subUid 65536" >> /var/lib/lxc/${CT}/config
echo "lxc.idmap = g 0 $subUid 65536" >> /var/lib/lxc/${CT}/config
```

Enabling user namespaces:

```
echo "kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1" > /etc/sysctl.d/80-lxc-userns.conf
sysctl --system
```

Update the default config for AppArmor LXC:

```
cat <<EOF >> /etc/lxc/default.conf
lxc.apparmor.allow_incomplete = 1
EOF
```

Enable cgroup kernel capabilities;
Edit /etc/default/grub from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 quiet"
```

here the details:
https://github.com/lucapiccio/LXC_to_Unprivileged/blob/main/convert.sh

You can find all the needed info in Readme.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Thanks for posting this, but please include the script _here_ so that the answer can stand on its own.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424444)

Comment: I've changed the post with all scripts steps details