# How to trust self-signed LXD daemon TLS certificate in Vagrant?

Tags: lxc, lxd

Following up from [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505073/3645) I've got the LXD daemon running and working:

```
$ curl --insecure https://127.0.0.1:8443
{"type":"sync","status":"Success","status_code":200,"operation":"","error_code":0,"error":"","metadata":["/1.0"]}
```

However, when trying to start a Vagrant container with the LXD provider it doesn't like the certificate:

```
$ vagrant up
The provider could not authenticate to the LXD daemon at https://127.0.0.1:8443.

You may need configure LXD to allow requests from this machine. The
easiest way to do this is to add your LXC client certificate to LXD's
list of trusted certificates. This can typically be done with the
following command:

    $ lxc config trust add /home/username/.config/lxc/client.crt

You can find more information about configuring LXD at:

    https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/#initial-configuration
```

There is no client.crt anywhere on my system. `lsof -p [PID of the program serving at port 8443]` doesn't list any certificates. `sudo locate .crt | grep lxd` found only `/var/lib/lxd/server.crt`, but `lxc config trust add /var/lib/lxd/server.crt` didn't help. The [configuration documentation](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/#initial-configuration) doesn't mention having to trust a certificate. I suspect I'm supposed to communicate with the daemon using a Unix socket rather than HTTPS. How do I move forward?

For the record I'm able to launch containers with for example `lxc launch ubuntu:18.10 test` and get a shell with `lxc exec test -- /bin/bash`, so LXC is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the wrong end of the stick. Looks like [creating a new certificate and trusting that](https://gitlab.com/catalyst-it/vagrant-lxd/issues/6) works:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ~/.config/lxc/client.key -nodes -out ~/.config/lxc/client.crt -subj "/CN=lxd.local"
lxc config trust add ~/.config/lxc/client.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the client.crt

You run

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8443
```

And copy and paste the first certificate it presents between and excluding the

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

and

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

lines.